# Get loop count and iterate loop based on count JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I have:

- A table which will have dynamic cells.
- All cells will have dynamic IDs.
- For loop which will get me how many cells are there in current table.
- After finding numbers of cells I will get its values and push it into an array.
- Ajax call to submit records.

What I am trying to achieve:

- If I have more then 500 cells in table; Let's say I have 2130 cells in table then I need to get first 500 cell records then push those values into an array. Submit values using Ajax clear array values; again get values from 501 to 1000 push it into an array and submit values using Ajax; again get values from 1001 to 1500 till we reach 2130.
- So what I need to do is break count values and loop through it till it gets all cell values.

  ```
  function getValues(){
      var lengthCount = document.getElementsByName('f05').length; //this will 
      get me how many cells are there 
      console.log("Number of cells " + lengthCount);
      var columnValue = document.getElementsByName('f05'); 
      var pushValues = [];

      for (var i=0; i < lengthCount ; i++){

          var storeItemValue = columnValue[i].value; // getting cell values
          pushValues.push(storeItemValue); // pushing cell values

      }

      //ajax call to submit values.

  }
  ```

Comment: Yes, i can but unfortunately where i submit the data using ajax call gives me internal server error so i need to break it in bunch and then submit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a condition to your `for`: on every iteration you can just check if it's time to send your `pushItems` with AJAX.
Just push your items and clear `pushItems` whenever you reach your 500 limit or it is the last item in your `columnValues`.

Something like that:

```
function postItems(items)
{
    return $.ajax(...);
}

function getValues() 
{
    var columnValue = document.getElementsByName('f05');

    // not a good idea if table may change during execution.
    // if some elements are removed after this line, then you may get an error during loop
    var lengthCount = columnValue.length; 

    console.log("Number of cells " + lengthCount);

    var pushValues = [], ajaxes = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < lengthCount; i++)
    {
        var storeItemValue = columnValue[i].value;
        pushValues.push(storeItemValue);

        if (i % 500 === 0 || i === lengthCount - 1)
        {
            var ajax = postItems(pushValues);
            pushValues = [];
        }
    }

    // $.when(...ajaxes).done(function() { <-- if you can use ES6
    $.when.apply($, ajaxes).done(function()
        alert("All done!");
    });
}
```

This solution is as close to your code as possible, and shows the idea. It can be improved or shortened, for example by using `Array.prototype.forEach`.